# How to deal with NA in the output of the linear regression in R, specifically NA for the three-way interaction terms?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

I am running a linear regression with three-way interaction in R
`lm(A~X * Y * Z)`, A=numerical variable, whereas X, Y, Z all are categorical variables with factors. X=5 factors, Y=2 factors, Z=4 factors. Every time I am running regression the three-way interaction for the last level is missing.

For e.g. if I relevel the Z factors, the last is getting dropped in the three-way interaction.

Coefficients: (8 not defined because of singularities). (This is mentioned in the R output)

I have tried using zero intercepts but it did not make any difference
`lm(A~ 0+ X * Y * Z)` or `lm(A~ X * Y * Z-1)` and all other possible combinations.

```
lm (A ~ X * Y * Z, data = dat)
```

X = 5 factors, Y = 2 factors and Z = 4 factors [one of the factors from each variable is acting as base level]

```
Coefficients: (8 not defined because of singularities)
```

Here are the 8 coefficients:

```
X(1):Y(1):Z(1)         NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(2):Y(1):Z(1)         NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(3):Y(1):Z(1)         NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(4):Y(1):Z(1)         NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(1):Y(1):Z(2)         NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(1):Y(1)              NA         NA      NA       NA    
Y(1):Z(1)              NA         NA      NA       NA    
X(1):Y(1):Z(3)         NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Other than above everything present in the output table

Comment: This is very hard to provide advice on because it is not clear what output you're getting. Can you paste in the output? Is the issue that you're getting a warning saying that your model is singular? Or is the issue that you are getting one less coefficient than you're expecting?

Comment: @Billy I am getting 8 less coefficients than expected. I have added the results from the R output in the question above.

Comment: How large is your sample? Given all the different interactions across all the various groups, my guess would be that there are some cells that have very few (possibly no) people in them. Alternatively, the issue is collinearity in the variables. You might try the `alias()` function around your fitted model

Comment: My sample size is 780, I have tried alias on my fitted model and it gives me 0 value for the terms which are showing NA in regression, but I can not figure why those values and is it fine to have those NA in the result

Comment: Are there any 1s in the output of `alias()`? It is a problem that you have NA outputs, and it increasingly is sounding like the issue is that your variables are linearly dependent. Do you need all of the interactions? Additionally, are you certain that there is are observations in every cell of your interactions? It's looking like Y1 is the trouble maker - are there very few people in this level?